# How to design models.py when I want to store the complex data like this?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm learning to use Django and try to design a system which aims to recommand musics.However,I am thrown into confusion when I think over how to design models.py.

Every song has its tags,such as 'sadness','hapiness','rock','R&B','jazz','male singer'...
  when a user like the music which has 'sadness' and 'rock' tags,I want to record it.

Should I design models.py like this:

```
class userItem(models.Model):
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tags_sadness=models.IntegerField()
    tags_rock=models.IntegerField()
    tags_...
```

When the user likes the music which has 'sadness' and 'rock' tags,
the value of tags_sadness and tags_rock will increase.

I believe it's not a good idea...Because there are soooooo many tags.But I'm a green hand when it come's to django and database...

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you for going like this:

```
class MusicTag(models.Model):
    tag=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class userItem(models.Model):
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tags= models.ManyToManyField(MusicTag)
```

So when you want to save the date, you can save like:

```
new_item= userItem() #model class
new_item.userName= "some data"
new_item.save()
if MusicTag.objects.filter(tag='R&R').exists():
   new_item.tags.add( MusicTag.objects.filter(tag='R&R')[0])
else:
   new_tag= MusicTag(tag='R&R')
   new_tag.save()
   new_item.tags.add(new_tag)
```

Now retrieving count for tags:

```
for item in MusicTag.objects.all():
    print item.tag , item.useritem_set.count()
```

Advantage of this model here is that you don't have to create model field for each tag and you can still get the counts for each tag.

Answer (score 0):

The tags can be recorded in a string splited by comma(or some other characters...) like this `"sad,R&B,rock"`.

```
class userItem(models.Model):
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    userTags = models.CharField(max_length=50) # max length of the tags
    ...
```